# toFixed method not working as expected in

Tags: javascript, angularjs

while working with large numbers i found some strange issue

```
(99999999999999.9).toFixed(2) returns "99999999999999.91"
```

where as

```
(99999999999999.8).toFixed(2) returns "99999999999999.80"
```

what I need is

```
(99999999999999.9).toFixed(2) should return "99999999999999.90"
```

how can I resolve this?

Comment: Probably you're bumping into float precision errors?

Comment: yes, Its a finacial application and even 1 paise is making differences here

Comment: If you need this level of precision I would recommend using a library. JS on it's own is not appropriate

Comment: please suggest some of the libraries

Comment: You've already had a suggestion in the answer below?

Answer (score 3):

You basically cannot do this, this is due to the representation of numbers in floating point and how javascript works in the background:

Javascript uses [IEEE 754 double precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) to represent symbols in memory 99999999999999.9 is displayed as

```
0 10000101101 0110101111001100010000011110100011111111111111111010
```

Which is a number consisting of 3 (integer) parts:

first the sign "0" means it's positive.

Then the exponent "multiplier" - `1069`. We subtract 1023 from it (to allow for negative exponents) so the multiplier is `2^(1069-1023)

And then the mantissa - "data" - `1.421085471520199`. -- calculation is shown on the wikipedia (without mathjax available a bit hard to show)

So the total value is +1.421085471520199*2^(1069-1023) = (according to wolfram alpha) 99999999999999.903472220635136

As you can see it isn't able to show that decimal precision exactly. This is due to limited mantissa,  we can see if we change the last bit of the mantissa, "1 higher" we get 9.99999999999999245828438884352 × 10^13 as result. and the one below is 9.99999999999998893984717996032 × 10^13 .

So everything between  9.99999999999998893984717996032 × 10^13 and 9.9999999999999903472220635136 × 10^13 is represented as the same number - you won't notice a difference there. [*]

Now as to why floating point is rounded "up" when displaying again in this case: that is a bit harder to explain but I guess it's due to the implementation.

---

Now could we predict this? And why doesn't it happen in decimal? This is easy to explain. A numberic system has different bases, normally we use "base 10", while computers use base 2 as intrinsic unit.

The choice has far fetched consequences: when working in a certain base you can only represent fractions that are a multiple of the prime factors of that base. IE base 10 has prime factors 2 and 5. So we can display any fraction that is a multiple of those:

```
1/2 => 0.5
1/5 => 0.2 
2/5 => 0.4 
1/10 = 1/2*1/5 => 0.1
```

However 1/3 cannot be described as a multiple of those two fractions, nor 1/7 or 1/6 - so in base 10 we can not write those as "decimals" down exactly.

Similarly base 2 has only the prime factor "2". a number ending with '.9' is in decimal always a fraction based on "1/5", which is not part of binary - thus cannot be described in binary.

---

now there are solutions, often there exist libraries that give so called "decimal" packages - which keep numbers in decimal representation, and replace the internal computer FPU with manual calculations.

[*]: ps I do not know if it's actually these boundaries - so if the floating point interpreter will always round up, or if the interpreter will round towards the nearest floating point. Someone with knowledge of the JS interpreters could answer that.

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely running into float precision error here.
If the specific usecase of yours is not needed to be extra sensitive you can use

```
(Math.round(yourValue*100)/100).toFixed(2)
```

There's also much more newer way of handling this using the [Intl.NumberFormat API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)

Playing especially with the fractions config

```
   minimumFractionDigits: 2,      
   maximumFractionDigits: 2
```

Ofcourse if you need some much more robust that plays well with other edge cases there's also [decimal.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decimal.js) to help out

```
var a = new Decimal(99999999999999.9);
console.log(a.toFixed(2))
```

Comment: (Math.round(99999999999999.9*100)/100).toFixed(2) returns "99999999999999.91"